# Create table if not exist each time API called: bad practice?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, php

I'm writing a simple API in PHP with MySQL as database for a web application. I intend to put `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST` for all tables in each API call.

I expect that I will have 5-6 tables.

I'm trying to do so for a simple reason: I will not need any extra script to run for initialization of the application - it will do it automatically on the first run.

As a drawback I expect that this can slow down API operation. However I tried to log API calls and it is still 2-3 milliseconds (in my case I did not notice any difference if there is CREATE TABLE or not).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems a bit of a strange thing to do, given the tables will only need to be created once.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I'm agree with you. However if there is no noticeable difference - why not?

Comment: It's an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ if it is: why I did not noticed any run time difference?

Comment: the problem as usually come when You already in troubles :) - it could be not as problem with low load, but could be serious bottleneck with high loading.

Comment: I mean this in the nicest possible way, but this seems like the product of poor software engineering and database design. Either you can use noSQL for unformatted data, or you should spend some more time wargaming out what data your customers will or may need in the future. This will help mitigate complexity down the road.

Answer (score 4):

So let's think forward a little. The application goes live, the tables are created and everything's lovely. Then, you have a new requirement and the tables must change. How do you code that? There's the CREATEs for environments where the code's never run, plus a bunch of ALTERs for existing environments. Now another requirement comes along. This time you have to migrate data for some reason or other. Now there are the CREATEs (for new environments), the ALTERs (for existing environments) and a whole bunch of DDL and migration logic. But wait - there's more. For really good business reasons you want the column holding the migrated data to have the same name as an existing column. How do you now tell if the database has been migrated or not? No longer do you have a metadata-only lookup. No, now you need a flag or version table to show what DDL has to run at each and every execution.

Yeah! You're a great success. Zillions of people want to use your service. Venture capitalists wheeling barrows of money to your door. Third-party organisations are begging to partner with you. The dev team's doubled (nay, trebled!) in size to handle the business opportunities and customisations. Oops. These all have to be coded in the API start-up code. Each. And. Every. One. You no longer have an API. You have the mother of all migration scripts with a fragment of business code tacked on. :sad-face:

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for overhead info the same reasons. **There is probably no overhead because the table is usually cached and there will be no disk access.** The bottleneck of databases is usually disk access.
However maybe a better solution will have following features:

1. You MUST have version table to track the database version. If you
   don't, at some point you'll get into trouble.
2. You must have migration script/function for each version  from the
   previous one and list of all published versions, so you can run them
   from the current database version up to the api version in the same
   order.
3. There could be a main migration script that will call scripts for
   each version. **This script can be run in target application tests,
   not in api calls**. It seems to me that updating database without
   monitoring is a bad  idea. A good application will have some kind of
   tests - for example unit tests, selenium, etc.
4. Sooner or later you'll get to a point where you can't update the
   database automatically because you've inserted new column/table
   which cannot be filled with default values and requires data. That's
   why update must be monitored. You throw a very descriptive exception
   which says what has to be done and a link to documentation with even
   more detailed description of migration process. The app developer
   makes a migration script, runs it and then runs API migration script
   again.
5. Because the manual steps described in 4 might be required to be in
   the middle of the migration script you can have migration steps for
   each migration script. The migration steps can be written into the
   version table. This way the update script could check at what stage
   it is and on next run it'll check if manual steps are done and
   continue from where it left.

Sounds complicated, but that's the difference between writing API and writing application. Unless your application must be installed on many servers...

Also if you design it well you won't have to get into complicated steps. Every version update script will be one step and will mostly add new tables or fields that could have default values. And if you design it really well most version updates won't need to update the database at all.